# Django add custom header in the shorthand render method

Tags: python, django

To add in a CORS settings I can do something like this on a particular function:

```
def clear(request):
    # ... something
    response = HttpResponse('OK')
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    return response
```

However, I'm having difficulty adding it on the shortform `render` method:

```
def function(request):
    # how to modify the response header here?
    return render(request, 'page.html', data)
```

How would I update some of the headers in the render response?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`render()` method combines a given `template` with a given `context dictionary` and returns an `HttpResponse` object with that rendered text. Refer [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render).

You can store the result of the render function in a variable called as response and then set cookies to it as you would normally do.

Your view function should be

```
def function(request):
    response = render(request, 'page.html', data)
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    return response
```

Comment: thanks for this, I think you'd want to set an HTTP header though and not a cookie? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.__setitem__

Comment: @David542 Yeah, thanks for pointing out. My bad, will edit the answer.

Answer (score 3):

[`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) also returns an `HttpResponse` object:

> Combines a given template with a given context dictionary and returns an `HttpResponse` object with that rendered text.

So you can do the exact same thing you did above on the 'raw' `HttpResponse` object:

```
def function(request):
    response = render(request, 'page.html', data)
    response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    return response
```